# symlinks are not included in BUILDROOT when using rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm using rpmbuild to build a set of rpms from source code that uses autotools. As part of the make install procedure symlinks are generated in the rpms/BUILD directory, however those symlinks are not copied into the BUILDROOT directory. As a result I get 
`error: file not found` messages from the rpmbuild process. My spec file includes the symlinks in the %files section, therefore rpmbuild expects the files to be there. For some reasons the rpmbuild process is not copying over the symlinks from the BUILD to the BUILDROOT directory. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a symlink, typically the simlink itself isn't copied because it is a link.  The "contents" of the symlink is copied, which is the file.

To fix this, use the `%install` section to create the desired symlinks in the `%{buildroot}` directory

```
ln -sf target %{buildroot}/link
```

and then package the link normally within the `%files` directive

```
%files
/link
```